# Running "Crusader Kings II"

Tags: wine, games

I am trying to run "Crusader Kings II" using wine, and a lot of workarounds suggest using WINEDEBUG command, but whenever i use it in terminal, it shows a message that command not found.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: There is Linux version for "Crusader Kings II," which won't require you to run it by wine. Have you tried that? Also, if you have a Steam-Key for "Crusader Kings II", you can install [Steam for Linux](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_under_Linux) and install and run your game from there.

Comment: @MadMike I know this was quite some time ago, but would you be willing to post that, or something like it, as an answer? I think that could still help people, and right now the only answer is about Wine.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me after I opened the console and entered:

```
winetricks d3dx9_36 dotnet20
```

I believe that `dotnet20` couldn't be installed, so probably the trick was in installing `d3dx9_36`. I'm running CK2 2.1.4 with ALL DLCs, and it works great. It takes longer to load the files at the beginning, but that's all.